# The pre hook is not working with find queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
/*The pre hook is supposed to populate the teacher field, but for some reason it didn't.Somehow when populate directly from the controller it works!*/

exports.getAssignment = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const assignment = await Assignment.findById(req.params.id).populate(
    'teacher'
  );
  if (!assignment) {
    return next(new AppError('No assignment found with this ID', 404));
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    assignment,
  });
});
  

/*But when I use with the pre hook it doesn't get excuted! */

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const assignmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    teacher: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    group: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' },
    AssignedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  },
  { toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } }
);

const Assignment = mongoose.model('Assignment', assignmentSchema);

assignmentSchema.pre('findById', function (next) {
  console.log('is this running');
  this.populate({
    path: 'teacher',
    select: 'firstName',
  });
  next();
});

module.exports = Assignment;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation for [`findById()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) it's stated that:

> This function triggers the following middleware.
>
> - `findOne()`

`findById()` is also not mentioned [in the list of query middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware).

So try this:

```
assignmentSchema.pre('findOne', function (next) { … })
```

Also, it's stated [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#defining) that middleware should be declared *before* creating the model:

```
assignmentSchema.pre('findOne', function (next) { … })

const Assignment = mongoose.model('Assignment', assignmentSchema);
```

Comment: I was compiling the model and then declare the pre middleware, I flipped them and the problem was fixed.